# Predicting missing data of DEM

Tags: dem, kriging

I am working with AWD3D-30m DEM which has many gaps (missing values). Can I utilize an older ASTER or SRTM DEM to predict that? Please answer in detail on what techniques to adopt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unaware of the differences in techniques, here is a quick introduction to the different methods that one can use while [kriging a raster surface to fix NA values](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/comparing-interpolation-methods.htm).

Firstly, one could use the Spatial Analyst extension in ArcMap to use the Kriging tool(Alternately, you could use the 3D Analyst extension). Below is a snapshot.

[image]

Above, one can choose the appropriate method, along with selecting the radius of cells you would like to use to interpolate values from.

Secondly, and I prefer this method, See - [fill the gaps using nearest neighbors](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181011/fill-the-gaps-using-nearest-neighbors). This question has been answered in detail using an example code written in R.