# Removing "Bow-tie deletion line " from my raster dataset

Tags: raster, gdal, geoprocessing, envi, satellite

I am working on VIIRS SDR dataset where I have created geolocated and projected raster of "BrightnessTemperature" using "Latitude" and "Longitude" dataset given in HDF5 format using ENVI. Now my study area comes under bow-tie deletion line as uploaded in image below.

[image: Red boundary is my studt area and thode white lines I want to remove.]

[image: Here is the zoomed in iage of study area.]

Comment: The red area is your study area? Can you zoom in on that and show the image, it might help a bit. There are standard techniques for filling in missing values in rasters, what have you tried?

Comment: Actually I am not getting which method will give me better result. I am thinking of trying Nearest neighbourhood but I dont know which tool should I use ?  I am putting zoomed image above in edited post.           @Spacedman

Comment: That's a lot of missing data there... what's the ultimate objective?

Comment: Yes exactly thts why i am confused in trying any of the method. objective is to get fire pixels feom running algorithm on different bands. Actually there is a way given in user's manual of dataset but I don't understand how to do it practically!!  If you can help me with it just check out page no.13 of link given below and guide me how to do it. @Spacedman https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g3XoghpAitPMOyFq1-20RTcO6Ps7ic0-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this the same question as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181011/fill-the-gaps-using-nearest-neighbors

Comment: Not exactly, but I can try that. If you have other suggestions please let me know. @Spacedman